# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INT_8 error while running spark job through oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INT_8 error when I am trying to execute a spark job using OOzie on Cloudera 5.5.1 version.
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Please find the error stackstrace below.

```
16/01/28 11:21:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 20.0 (TID 40, Zlab-physrv1): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INT_8
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:312)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convertField$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:516)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:312)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convertField(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:312)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:305)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:92)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.CatalystSchemaConverter.convert(CatalystSchemaConverter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetTypesConverter$.convertFromAttributes(ParquetTypesConverter.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.RowWriteSupport.init(ParquetTableSupport.scala:55)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:277)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As per My idea normally we used to get this error when ever there is some difference on the jars you have used to generate the code and the jars you have used currently.

Note: When I am trying to submit the Same one using spark-submit command it's running fine.

Regards
Nisith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Able to debug and fix the issue. The Issue was with the installation as one of the data nodes are having older version of parquet Jars(5.2 cdh distribution). After replacing the jars with the current version jars it was working fine.